# No data exists for the row/column vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Path variable is defined globally.
Values of er.item(0),er.item(1), er.item(2),er.item(2),er.item(3) are not accessible after reader object has used item(0). What is wrong?

here is the code

Private Sub load_qc_by()

```
    Dim dname = CategoryDropDown2.Text
    con.ConnectionString = path
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SQC_By,PQC_By,FQC_By,CQC_By FROM Deliverables WHERE Deliverable ='" & dname & "' AND Project='" & ProjectDropDown2.Text & "'"
    Dim er As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If er.HasRows Then
        While er.Read

            If (er.Item(0).ToString.Equals("NA")) Then
                Call load_all_Names("sqcby_combobox")
                sqcby_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0

            Else
                MessageBox.Show(er.Item(0))
                sqcby_combobox.Text = er.Item(0).ToString
                sqcby_combobox.Enabled = False
            End If

            If (er.Item(1).ToString.Equals("NA")) Then
                Call load_all_Names("pqcby_combobox")
                pqcby_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0
            Else
               MessageBox.Show(er.Item(1))
                pqcby_combobox.Text = er.Item(1)
                pqcby_combobox.Enabled = False
            End If

            If (er.Item(2).ToString.Equals("NA")) Then
                Call load_all_Names("fqcby_combobox")
                fqcby_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(er.Item(2))
                fqcby_combobox.Text = er.Item(2)
                fqcby_combobox.Enabled = False
            End If
            If (er.Item(3).ToString.Equals("NA")) Then
                Call load_all_Names("cqcby_combobox")
                cqcby_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(er.Item(3))
                cqcby_combobox.Text = er.Item(3)
                cqcby_combobox.Enabled = False
            End If
        End While
    End If

        er.Close()
        con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess would be that your `load_all_Names` method closes the connection or the data reader. If so then this is a perfect example of why you should not have global variables for things like connections but rather use local variables and then create and destroy the objects when and where you need them.

Comment: A  big thankyou...i just couldnt understand where the problem was from 2 days. I created a new connection object and established a new connection with accdb and it works just fine.